# impala incremental last modified

Tags: sqoop, last-modified

I have a `Sqoop` import to bring in data from Oracle with a join on two tables. I need to do a `--incremental last-modified` based on a column which is common on both the tables:

`--query "SELECT customer_info.customer_id, customer_info.customer_name,
    customer.date_created, sales_info.last_update_date as sales_last_update_date 
    from customer_info
    inner join
    sales_info ON customer_info.customer_id = sales_info.customer_id 
    AND \$CONDITIONS" \
    --split-by "customer_id" \
    --fields-terminated-by '\t' \
    --target-dir (name_of_dir) \
    --incremental lastmodified \
    --check-column sales_last_update_date \`

The `last_update_date` is common on both the columns.

But I get the error:

```
ORA-00904: "sales_last_update_date": invalid identifier
```

Comment: try `last_update_date` instead

Comment: using last_update_date, it throws an error:

Comment: Column ambiguously defined

Comment: try to add table name sales_info.last_update_date

Comment: doesn't work that way, same error: invalid identifier